# moving file pointer in c# to a line containing specific string

Tags: c#

I want some way to read from a `.txt` file in a way that I want to move pointer to a specific position and then read my `.txt` file containing strings in blocks like below

```
BLOCK1
string1
string2
string3
.....
.....
ENDOFBLOCK
BLOCK2
string1
string2
string3
.....
.....
ENDOFBLOCK
BLOCK3
string1
string2
string3
......
......
ENDOFBLOCK
```

Instead of reading file from beginning I want to move pointer to line containing string `BLOCK2` and read up to line containing string `ENDOFBLOCK`. I want some method of C# that it searches a string in a file.
If found then it moves pointer in file to line containing that string and read file line by line up to a specific string. I hope I was
able to tell clearly what I want to do. Actually I am making an application of urdu language that's why I was unable to share actual code as example.

Comment: Do you know at what position the blocks start? If not, you won't be able to accomplish this.

Comment: You'll have to read it from the beginning unless you have some separate index for it

Comment: the problem is i dont know at what position block starts

Comment: See my solution in following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457660/parsing-multi-sections-of-a-text-file-using-regex-in-c-sharp/30458775#30458775

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"c:\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                string line = "";
                while (line != "BLOCK2" && line != null)
                {
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }

                line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                while (line != "ENDOFBLOCK" && line != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u.it looks that this code will do what i want.i ll try it and tell.

Answer (score 0):

since you dont know where block2 begins, you need to read the file from the top till you reach the string block2.(untested example)

```
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != "BLOCK2"){}
//block2 found
while((line = file.ReadLine())  != "ENDOFBLOCK") {
//this is what you want
}
```

Comment: The question is about C# :)

Comment: damn! thats why i prefer java:) this should be ok, i think

Answer (score 0):

thanks venerik and every body for help.below code worked for me.actually i did not know that a specific BLOCK occurred in file or not.so i have to read a file to end first and break if BLOCK found

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    String stringfound;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void clickhandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String line;
        try
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader("d:\\test.txt");


                while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null )
                {
                    if (line.Contains("BLOCK2")) 
                    {
                        stringfound=line;
                        break;


                    }


                }

            if(stringfound=="BLOCK2") // checking if BLOCK2 exists or not
            {
                while (line != "ENDOFBLOCK" && line != null)
                {
                    line = file.ReadLine();


                }
            }
            else                 // BLOCK2 not found
            {
               // do something else  
            }



        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("unknown exception occurred");
        }


    }
}
```

}