# Extract text from large file using RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have a big file that has a bunch of data in it, but essentially what I would like to do is to grab only parts of it, let me explain what parts I'm interested in:

(imagine "x" as an IP Address)

(imagine "?" as any alphanumerical character /w any length)

(imagine "MD5" as an MD5 hash)

*(Actual -not literally though- text file below)*

---

```
'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

xxxxxxxxxx

'?'

'?'

'MD5'
```

---

Now my inquiry is the following one, How could I identify the line

> ***'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'***

anywhere at the beginning inside a file and then automatically write to another file both of the '?' entries and the 'MD5' entry for each IP Address instances found.

So in a nutshell, the program should start at the beginning of the file, read the contents, if it hits an IP Address (`Regex: '\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b'` works fine for me), skip one line below, then start copying the other data to another file until it hits the MD5 entry (`Regex: '[a-f0-9]{32}'` works fine for me), then iterate again from that point and so on *looking for another instance of an IP Address* etc, etc. It should keep doing that until it reaches the end of the file.

I'm trying to do this myself but I don't even know where to start, or methods of doing it at all.

Comment: What is the second line of `x`, the one without dots?

Comment: @Tomalak, Some ID number, is not for relative importance.

Comment: I would not use Regex to read the file.  Use code like my code on following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457660/parsing-multi-sections-of-a-text-file-using-regex-in-c-sharp/30458775#30458775.  You could use Regex to identify if a line contain an IP, but don't use regex on entire file.  Please post actual section of file so I can help.  Been doing text parsing for over 40 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match the content that you are looking for.. and copy it to the desired location/ file:

```
('\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b')(\s*.+\s*)([\s\S]*?)('\b[a-f0-9]{32}\b')
```

And extract `$1$3$4`

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%27%5Cb%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5Cb%27)(%5Cs*.%2B%5Cs*)(%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F)(%27%5Cb%5Ba-f0-9%5D%7B32%7D%5Cb%27)&i=%27217.82.21.54%27%0D%0A1410741930%0D%0A%27user1%27%0D%0A%27user1%27%0D%0A%272b450a82ee00c2257650d4de33e4aced%27%0D%0A123%0D%0Asdasd%0D%0Aasdxcfewef%0D%0A0%0D%0Asdfsdf%0D%0A%27217.82.21.54%27%0D%0A1410741930%0D%0A%27user2%27%0D%0A%27user2%27%0D%0A%272b450a82ee00c2257650d4de33e4aced%27%0D%0Aasdxcfewef%0D%0A123%0D%0Asdasd%0D%0A0%0D%0Asdfsdf%0D%0A%27217.82.21.54%27%0D%0A1410741930%0D%0A%27user3%27%0D%0A%27user3%27%0D%0A%272b450a82ee00c2257650d4de33e4aced%27%0D%0Asdfsdf%0D%0Asdasd%0D%0A0%0D%0A123%0D%0Aasdxcfewef%0D%0A%27217.82.21.54%27%0D%0A1410741930%0D%0A%27user4%27%0D%0A%27user4%27%0D%0A%272b450a82ee00c2257650d4de33e4aced%27)

Code:

```
String regex = "('\\b\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\b')(\\s*.+\\s*)([\\s\\S]*?)('\\b[a-f0-9]{32}\\b')";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(myString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("end(): " + m.group(1));
    //System.out.println("end(): " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("end(): " + m.group(3));
    System.out.println("end(): " + m.group(4));
}
```

Comment: Your regex yields "0 matches found" on my end.

Comment: @manchala https://regex101.com/r/eZ6lU9/1 - that's one part of the actual text file. you can evaluate your regex over there too as I'm doing.

Comment: @AxDSanMuramasa `regex101` doesnot support c#.. i am using `regexstorm` for testing.. check the demo in the answer..

Comment: I see now, You could check now this [REGEX Real World Application Simulation](http://goo.gl/eG8PpQ) as you notice it's a bit closer now, however the IP Address identification needs some work, and actually I would like to skip, the line below the IP Address, and identify the 2 users + MD5

Comment: @AxDSanMuramasa can you updtae the question with expected output?

Comment: Getting closer to what I'm looking for, however, it identifies the last single quote of the IP (I want the whole address idenfitied) identifies the xxxxxxxx line, which is the one I want to skip, it doesn't identifies the MD5, and after the MD5 I don't really know what are those blue lines... does it stands for ignoring it them or identifying?

Comment: @AxDSanMuramasa check the demo now.. and you can see the matched string and parts by clicking `table` at the end of the page in demo.. you can extract `$1` for IP.. `$3` for users and `$4` for MD5..

Comment: Excellent just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that your file is machine generated and that the overall pattern is pretty specific, I don't think it's necessary to be overly specific with the IP address.

Matching it as "a bunch of digits and dots in single quotes" is probably enough, in the context of the rest of the pattern (*).

Here is an expression that matches your entire requirement into [named groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#named_matched_subexpression):

```
^'(?<IP>[\d.]+)'\s+
^(?<ID>\w*)\s+
^'(?<line1>\w*)'\s+
^'(?<line2>\w*)'\s+
^'(?<MD5>[A-Fa-f0-9]{32})'
```

Use it with the `Multiline` and `IgnorePatternWhitespace` [regex options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) (the latter means you can keep the regex layout for better readability).

---

(*) Besides, regex patterns for IP addresses are literally all over the place, in countless examples. Of course you can use something more sophisticated than `'[\d.]+'` if you think it's necessary.

Comment: This is a more convenient approach, however how could I iterate through each element that I find...? should I use a for loop and identify them?

Comment: Yes, and the .NET regex documenation and many answers and code samples all over the internet show you how that is done. It's a really basic matter that you will easily figure out on your own. The point of my answer was more to highlight a few useful features of. NET regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried out this in Java as below.

public class TestRegex
{

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "assasasa 123.234.223.223 333 aad sddsf 343sdd sds23343 ssdfs33344 MD5=aas jjsjjdjd 143.234.223.223 333 aad sddsf 343sdd sds23343 ssdfs33344 MD5=asas";
    String regexPattern = "(\\b[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\b).*?([A-Z a-z]+[0-9]+=.*?\\s)";
    Matcher m = null;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
    m = pattern.matcher(input);
    // System.out.println(matcher.toString());
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("start(): " + m.start());
        System.out.println("end(): " + m.end());
        System.out.println("end(): " + m.toString());
        System.out.println("end(): " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("end(): " + m.group(2));
    }

}
```

}