# How to read line by line in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can read line by line  at the below expression?

```
CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:57:23
san-ls-02022;ENEXRHO;1505;{call Pm_I_AuthFailToPTSF(631706,-21,?)}
ass
bbbb
CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:57:23
631706
aaa
bbb
```

I want to write this expression current time to current time .
For example :

```
(?<=(?<=CurrentTime\=)[0-9].*)\n(.*)
```

I wrote this formula but it didn't solve my problem.It is only read one line after the current time. But I want to read all line :

```
san-ls-02022;ENEXRHO;1505;{call Pm_I_AuthFailToPTSF(631706,-21,?)}
ass
bbbb
```

to other current time flag.

Comment: Actually in this regex : (CurrentTime\=.*)((\n.*)+)(CurrentTime\=.*) the second group ((\n.*)+) gives me lines between "CurrentTimes".. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?sm)^CurrentTime=([^\n]*)\n(.*?)(?=^CurrentTime=|\z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG8kW0/3)

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of a line (since the `/m` modifier is used)
- `CurrentTime=` - the sequence of literal characters `CurrentTime=`
- `([^\n]*)\n` - matches and captures into Group 1 zero or more characters other than a newline and will just match the following newline
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 capturing zero or more any characters (incl. a newline since the DOTALL `/s` modifier is used) but as few as possible, up to the first
- `(?=^CurrentTime=|\z)` - `CurrentTime=` at the beginning of a line, or the end of string (`\z`)

**Performance Update**

To unroll the current regex, just use negated character classes with some additional grouping and a negative lookahead:

```
(?m)^CurrentTime=([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*(?:\n(?!CurrentTime=)[^\n]*)*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG8kW0/4)

In .NET:

```
var input = "CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:57:23\nsan-ls-02022;ENEXRHO;1505;{call Pm_I_AuthFailToPTSF(631706,-21,?)}\nass\nbbbb\nCurrentTime=04/24/16 09:57:23\n631706\naaa\nbbb\n"; 
var pat = @"(?m)^CurrentTime=([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*(?:\n(?!CurrentTime=)[^\n]*)*)";
var results = Regex.Matches(input, pat)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(p => p.Groups[2].Value)  // Get the capture group 2 values
            .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n---\n", results));
```

See the [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/kroQET)

See [regex demo at RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fm)%5ECurrentTime%3D(%5B%5E%5Cn%5D*)%5Cn(%5B%5E%5Cn%5D*(%3F%3A%5Cn(%3F!CurrentTime%3D)%5B%5E%5Cn%5D*)*)&i=CurrentTime%3D04%2F24%2F16%2009%3A57%3A23%0D%0Asan-ls-02022%3BENEXRHO%3B1505%3B%7Bcall%20Pm_I_AuthFailToPTSF(631706%2C-21%2C%3F)%7D%0D%0Aass%0D%0Abbbb%0D%0ACurrentTime%3D04%2F24%2F16%2009%3A57%3A23%0D%0A631706%0D%0Aaaa%0D%0Abbb%0D%0A)

Comment: It is the easiest way to build the pattern (the lazy dot matching pattern with the positive lookahead to follow), you can unroll it for better performance.

Comment: what OP wants is only : `san-ls-02022;ENEXRHO;1505;{call Pm_I_AuthFailToPTSF(631706,-21,?)}
ass
bbbb` OP doesn't want the timestamp after CurrentTime..

Comment: I have just modified the answer - please make sure you really want to skip the first line or not. Or maybe you can use [`(?m)^CurrentTime=([^\n]*)\n(.*?)(?=^CurrentTime=|\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/uG8kW0/3). I updated the answer to show how to enhance the grouping inside the pattern.

Comment: Now it is betten than the other Wiktor.Thanks

Comment: Wiktor it is not working for .net. I need for .net regex :(

Comment: Glad you mentioned that finally :) Do you know how to get all matches/groups in C#/VB.NET?

Comment: I took the liberty and edited the PCRE-style regex strings into regexes that work with .NET. I hope that wasn't unwanted, but as the answer stood, it was less than helpful for people who don't know how different regex engines introduce skeuomorphic syntax elements (e.g. the delimiter and options in PCRE).

Comment: I dont know  get all matches/groups in C#/VB.NET wiktor :(

Comment: The regexps worked in the .NET as is, I just used the *PHP regexes*. I thought you needed it for PHP... OK,  I will provide the code showing how to get those strings.

Comment: Very very thanks Wiktor :) now it is working fine for .net. I can use now in my project :)

Comment: Hi Wiktor,I want to ask another question .If you give answer I will happy.How can do for lots of currenttime list in .net .Because you give example only one currenttime.but I have file in lots of currenttime.

Comment: Not sure I get you: `Regex.Matches` returns the list of *all* matches.

Comment: for example : I have one file :CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:57:22
san-ls-02022;ENEXRHO;1025;8099123000000001390;052;;0.0000;0.0000;2527;;0;4
2
CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:57:23
san-ls-02022;ENEXRHO;1505;{call Pm_I_AuthFailToPTSF(631706,-21,?)}

CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:57:23
631706
CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:58:02
san-ls-02022;ENEXRHO;1025;8099123000000001390;052;;0.0000;0.0000;13

CurrentTime=04/24/16 09:58:03
6
200000.0000
1
DIESEL
2103590
CurrentTime=04/24/16 10:04:02
san02022;ENEXRHO;1025;8099122000000002524;052;;0.0000;0.0000;20
CurrentTime=04/24/16 10:04:03
4
545000.0000
3

Comment: I have to read file after parse with regex and I will write in datagridview

Comment: Can you add that text to the question with proper newlines? [My code above should handle the string well](https://regex101.com/r/bP2gL0/1).

Comment: I have to read in file after I have to do regex match  to take date and other words :(

Comment: Reading in a text file? That is basic, search SO and you will find something like `using (var sr = new StreamReader(filepath, true)) { var s = ""; while((s=sr.ReadLine()) != null) { /*s contains the line, process it, and go on*/ } }`

Comment: yes I know reading in a text file I did it your way but how can adjust for regex match ? because sr.readline read line by line.

Comment: Read all the file with [ReadAllText](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalltext) or is it too large?

Comment: ok I can read all lines but after how can I parse within currentime tags ?do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi Wiktor ,do you have any answer ?

Comment: I think I have answered a very similar question some time ago. I need to check, the point is that you need to analyze each line and once it starts with the leading delimiter, you keep grabbing next lines until the trailing delimiter.

Comment: how can I keep grabbing the other lines? I  confuse little bit.

Comment: Please check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457660/parsing-multi-sections-of-a-text-file-using-regex-in-c-sharp/30458276#30458276. I am feeding my daughter now, if you have trouble, I will provide a sample code

Comment: Hi Wiktor .Thanks for your helps .I have to need one regex expiression for this :[16-04-22 23:34:32.692]   FROM SCU:=<orpt_setmode mask="02" enabled="yes" device_id="T4" />     I have to seperate date and text it is only one line.it is easy than current time.I have to two regex.First will take only date.The other expression will take start FROM and it will take all words unti the end of line.

Comment: Something like [`@"\[([^][]*)]\s*(.*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/eA7nK5/1) should help, `Groups[1].Value` and `Groups[2].Value` will hold the texts you need.

Comment: very very thanks Wiktor.Lastly ENEXBOS 20160424 070154 StdProcess BGN .how can separate without ENEXBOS    :  group 1 = 20160424 070154   and group2=StdProcess BGN will be.

Comment: Very Thanks Wiktor for your helps :)

Comment: Wiktor I have problem for first regex match currenttime. I take date but it is coming in code 04/25/16 09:57:17\r     \r leading problem for date parser .how can I solved ?

Comment: If you mean the first regex in the answer, then just add `\r` to the negated char class: `[^\n\r]`. `(?sm)^CurrentTime=([^\r\n]*)\r?\n(.*?)(?=^CurrentTime=|\z)`. Unrolled: `(?m)^CurrentTime=([^\r]*)\r([^\r]*(?:\r(?!CurrentTime=)[^\r]*)*)`.

Comment: Wiktor your first answer good for me .but in .net I can try  take date is coming 04/25/16 09:57:17\r  this format.I dont understand why insert to end line \r .it is giving problem for format date.

Comment: I have to do this only date part.The other part good for me .

Comment: Well, if you do not need a CR, just use `.Trim()` to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace.